# Using a union function after a join. Getting sqlite3.OperationalError for order_by before the union

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

First, I managed to solve it, but I don't understand why my first approach is not working. Will be happy for some help.
I used an order_by to join and got an error if I tried to union the result

This is for Flask and sqlalchemy on sqlite3 database.

I know this is redundant, I tried joining two tables and union the resulte with another query. When sorting (order_by) the join, I get an exception in the union.

Original approach -

```py
    def followed_posts(self):
        followed = Post.query.join(
            followers,
            (followers.c.followed_id == Post.user_id)
        ).filter(
            followers.c.follower_id == self.id
        ).order_by(
            Post.timestamp.desc()
        )
        return followed.union(self.posts)
```

This failed with: "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "UNION": syntax error"

When I try to return `followed` without the union, there is no error. but this is not what I need.

```
    def followed_posts(self):
        followed = Post.query.join(
            followers,
            (followers.c.followed_id == Post.user_id)
        ).filter(
            followers.c.follower_id == self.id
        ).order_by(
            Post.timestamp.desc()
        )
        return followed
```

when I move the order_by from the join to the union it works with no problem.

```
    def followed_posts(self):
        followed = Post.query.join(
            followers,
            (followers.c.followed_id == Post.user_id)
        ).filter(
            followers.c.follower_id == self.id
        )
        return followed.union(self.posts).order_by(Post.timestamp.desc())
```

So it is solved, but I don't understand why the original approach returned an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returned an error because you tried to do something that sqlite doesn't allow.

From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

> In a compound SELECT, all the constituent SELECTs must return the same number of result columns. As the components of a compound SELECT must be simple SELECT statements, they may not contain ORDER BY or LIMIT clauses. ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses may only occur at the end of the entire compound SELECT, and then only if the final element of the compound is not a VALUES clause.

and

> In a compound SELECT statement, only the last or right-most simple SELECT may have an ORDER BY clause. That ORDER BY clause will apply across all elements of the compound. If the right-most element of a compound SELECT is a VALUES clause, then no ORDER BY clause is allowed on that statement.